# NPM is known not to run on Node.js v9.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

Why I use NPM to install something, it will have this problem as below

> ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v9.2.1
> Node.js 9 is supported but the specific version you're running has
> a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 9.0.0 to use this
> version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/

Then I find some solutions at Stack Overflow.

> [npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0/47251344)
>
> [npm does not support Node.js v9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044126/npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-0-0)

Almost every answer suggest to use `npm uninstall -g npm` first. But when I use this command, it will have the same error as above.

My npm version is 6.13.7

My node version is 9.2.

Comment: And upgrading your node version is not an option? Because I think that would be the best thing to do otherwise

Comment: You shouldn't be using Node 9 at all at this point, and if you're not in a position to be confidently upgrading should probably not have been using an odd-numbered, non-LTS version: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Answer (score 2):

Basically node js 9.2... version is compatible with npm version 5.5.1.
So I will provide you the following suggestion.

1. if you want to work with node js 9.2 only then

   1. uninstall node js 9.2
   2. uninstall npm
   3. install node js 9.2
   4. then install npm version 5.5.1 -        **npm install -g npm@5.5.1**
2. update node js and npm to the latest version and check your code compatibility with the new version.

To do this

1. install node js latest version
2. **npm install -g npm@latest**

Answer (score 2):

In short, you accidentally upgrade `npm`, `Node v9.2.0` using `npm v5.5.1` as default,

while the default `npm v6.13.7` of `node` is `node v13.10.0`.

In order to use `Node v9.2.0` again, just use below code on your terminal:

```
cd ~ && nvm install v13.10.0
nvm uninstall v9.2.0
nvm install v9.2.0
nvm uninstall v13.10.0
```

END!

Others, a long long book about [this question(GitHub Gist)](https://gist.github.com/SofijaErkin/4f59f5a56f509f15aac667840e7aa9e1).

Comment: This reads like a book not an answer

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, please just only read the top short summary solution as the answer, not the bottom long long book, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I use `nvm` for managing the node versions.

**Previously I had these versions installed:**

- NVM -> `1.1.7`
- Node.js -> `14.18.3`
- NPM -> `6.14.15`

**Then upgraded to these versions:**

- NVM -> `1.1.7` (still same)
- Node.js -> `18.16.0`
- NPM -> `9.5.1`

**System:** `Windows`

The installation was successful and verified by the `node --version` & `npm --version` commands.

But then, the `npm` commands started failing showing the same error. I tried some ways like updating node and npm separately, re-installing everything, etc. but the issue was still there.

Finally, after some investigation I found that my `nvm` version was pretty old at `1.1.7` and I tried updating the `nvm` version to the latest at `1.1.11` and then everything started working as expected with upgraded Node.js and NPM versions. **Done!!**

You can download the latest `nvm`(for Windows only) from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases).

You can see the Node.js & NPM compatible versions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases).

P.S.: The `nvm` every time installs the compatible versions of Node.js and NPM for every version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete manually directory `npm` and `npm-cache` in ... **AppData/Roaming**
2. Run in your terminal `npm cache clean --force`
3. Install your package `npm install -g cordova ionic`